# get json data from wcf service without using [WebGet(ResponseFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json)]

Tags: wcf

I want to create a example wcf service that return data as JSON.
But i do not want to use [WebGet(ResponseFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json)] because I think
then my service contract will kind of polluted. Because the whole point of using WCF is to create WCF and then using endpoint to get the new type like JSON/ C# etc.

Is there any way I create a wcf service and then using config to get json data by adding service behaviour and specific enpoint
May be I am thinking wrong.

Thanks,
Daljit Singh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try looking at WCF WebHttpService, as it can be configured to explictly set the format or automatically set the format based on the request.  The default setting is automatically set the format, and the service will try to determine the format of the response in the following order:

1. The value of the HTTP Accept header of the request.
2. The content-type of the request.
3. The default format response for the operation.

There's a blog post on this here:  [Automatic and Explicit Format Selection in WCF WebHttp Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/18/automatic-and-explicit-format-selection-in-wcf-webhttp-services.aspx)

The entire series (well, the first 10 of the 12 parts, the last two have not been posted as far as I can find) is here:  [Introducing WCF WebHttp Services in .NET 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/06/introducing-wcf-webhttp-services-in-net-4.aspx)

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but it might help.